# Filter dictionary with arrays as value

Tags: swift

I have dictionary  `[String: [Object]]`. Each object has `.name`

Is it possible to use `.filter` on dictionary to return dictionary with only keys that contain filtered value ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the **keys** of a `[String: [Object]]` dictionary where each `Object` has a `name` property and this property has a given value.

```
struct Obj {
    let name: String
}

let o1 = Obj(name: "one")
let o2 = Obj(name: "two")
let o3 = Obj(name: "three")

let dict = ["a": [o1, o2], "b": [o3]]
```

*Now let's say you want the dictionary key where an object has "two" for its name:*

**Solution with `filter`**

```
let filteredKeys = dict.filter { (key, value) in value.contains({ $0.name == "two" }) }.map { $0.0 }

print(filteredKeys)
```

**Solution with `flatMap` and `contains`**

```
let filteredKeys = dict.flatMap { (str, arr) -> String? in
    if arr.contains({ $0.name == "two" }) {
        return str
    }
    return nil
}

print(filteredKeys)
```

**Solution with a loop**

```
var filteredKeys = [String]()

for (key, value) in dict {
    if value.contains({ $0.name == "two" }) {
        filteredKeys.append(key)
    }
}

print(filteredKeys)
```

Comment: Thats a really great an perfect answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but since you got a Dictionary with an array as value:

```
dictionary.flatMap({ $0.1.filter({ $0.name == "NameToBeEqual"}) })
```

Comment: Thanks! I try to filter with the search string filteredCityStations.filter({ $0.1.filter({ $0.title!.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)}) }) - but it complains that my type cannot be converted to Bool.

Comment: @AlexeyK, EricD is right, the first filter should be a flatMap, I edited my answer.